# Elementree Fromstring and iterparse in Python 3.x

Tags: python

I am able to parse from file using this method:

for event, elem in ET.iterparse(file_path, events=("start", "end")):

But, how can I do the same with fromstring function?  Instead of from file, xml content is stored in a variable now.  But, I still want to have the events as before.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for the iterparse method:

> ...Parses an XML section into an element tree incrementally, and
>   reports what’s going on to the user. source is a filename or file
>   object containing XML data...

I've never used the etree python module, but "or file object" says to me that this method accepts an open file-like object as well as a file name.  It's an easy thing to construct a file-like object around a string to pass as input to a method like this.

Take a look at the StringIO module.

Comment: Perfect.  I was looking for a way to convert a string to a file object.  StringIO works